# ¿Anclar pantalla de aplicación android en versión previa a 5.0 lollipop?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

¿Conocen alguna manera de fijar la pantalla de la aplicación como se puede hacer en android 5.0, pero en versiones anteriores?

De antemano agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, podrias explicar mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: Android 5.0 tengo entendido que añadio una opcion en sus ajustes para poder anclar una aplicacion y asi no poder salir de esta sin el ingreso de tu clave de desboqueo ya sea pin o patron.

Comment: Estoy buscando una forma de replicar esto pero en una versión anterior a 5.0

Comment: Bizza, te sugiero revisar [ask] y realizar tus preguntas en base a este documento para que obtengas la ayuda requerida, trata de aportar datos e información necesaria. ¿Esta pregunta esta relacionada a esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/195843/como-limitar-el-acceso-a-los-usuarios-exclusivamente-a-la-aplicacion ?

Comment: Si, lo siento por repetir el tema, pero creí haberme explicado bien esta vez ya que antes no sabia que las versión 5.0 en adelante contaba con la funcionalidad de fijar pantalla, leeré el Cómo preguntar para intentar formular mejor mi pregunta, muchas gracias.